# Prevent IO access from Powershell running inside c# program

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have an online form that allows entering the PowerShell script. I later execute this script on the back end with c#
For security reasons, I don't want to allow IO access to the PowerShell script (E.G. reading or writing files to the disk).
How can I do it?

```
 InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
 Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
 rs.Open();
 string powershel="some powershell script here";
 using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
 {
            powerShellInstance.Runspace = rs;
            powerShellInstance.AddScript(powershell);
            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = powerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```

I am using .Net framework 4.7.2

Comment: You can do it by not accepting arbitrary code from your users :-)

Comment: With the setup you're describing local file access would be the least of my concern

Comment: One option is not to do it as it was commented. Second option is to suggest something more clever then "don't do it"